# Dates are being changed when moving data from oracle server

Tags: sql, r, oracle, date, rodbc

I'm using the RODBC library to move data from an oracle server to R. I've tried using this:

```
dataframe <- sqlQuery(connect,
 "SELECT *
  FROM 
  *****.******", as.is=T
)
```

and this:

```
dataframe <- sqlQuery(connect,
 "SELECT *
  FROM 
 *****.*******"
)
```

The data seems to import fine, however when I try to check the dates using:

```
unique(dataframe$DATEREFSUBMITTED)
```

I get a range of dates that does not match the data itself. The data, on average, is 2 years older than reality (I assume this means a data point dated in 2016 now says 2014). I know the correct dates because I've used SAS to import this data and have checked out the data itself on the server using ORACLE SQL developer.

Has anyone had experience with this issue before? I know that dates can be an issue moving from different versions of excel to R, is this what is happening here?

Here is an example of the problem:
The dates on the left were extracted with R using the RODBC functions and the ones the right were extracted using SAS, then I matched them on their ID. There doesn't seem to be a clear pattern.

1) 2014-01-07 00:00:00 **(VS)** 1/7/2014 <- these two are the same

2) 2013-10-28 00:00:00 **(VS)** 6/21/2011 <- not the same, year and date

3) 2013-08-06 00:00:00 **(VS)** 12/6/2011 <- " "

4) 2012-03-01 00:00:00 **(VS)** 3/1/2012 <- just one year later

Also should note: this is a government computer, so I doubt I can change too many settings.

fyi: (DateREFSUBMITTED data type is Date in ORACLE SQL and is a POSIXct class in R)

Comment: It might help if you could provide a few specific examples of what the dates are in Oracle and what that specific date ends up as in R. Also, some info on the table/field definitions might help people narrow things down.

Comment: ill edit the code to address this